# Numerically Solving EM problems. Book covering: ABS, PML, Near field calcul., LU fact, BicGstab, Pardiso etc

Tags: resource-recommendations, computational-physics, software, algorithms

I looking for a book (or two) covering a range of topics:

- numerical implementation of
  boundary conditions (PEC, PMC, ABS);
- perfect matching layer;
- LU factorisation;
- numerical solvers and when to use them (solvers like BicGstab, Pardiso, 
  MUMPS);
- things like, convergence, accuracy, precision;

Problems which I will have to solve in the near future:

- finding resonances and Purcell factors of nanoantenna(s) quantum dot
  systems in a layered medium;
- modes in and S matrix of micro waveguides. Numerical propagation of Gaussian beam in that waveguide;
- energy transport from dipole along a plasmonic wire;

Probably I will solve all of these problems in the frequency domain. Tools I have: COMSOL, Matlab, Mathematica and Python.

A little about me:

I am stuck with one of my projects which requires numerical calculation (Which I am doing in COMSOL and Matlab). I haven't done any progress in more than a year. I have almost no background in numerical calculations.

I would like to do a good job and be able to quantify how much I can trust my results.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/161368/25301