# Computational Physics Resources

Tags: resource-recommendations, computational-physics

I was wondering if anybody could please recommend any computational physics books please?

I have a background in data science and I picked up the effective computation physics book by Kathryn Huff up. I’ve found that it’s more of an introduction to Python programming using examples from physics.

Where would you consider looking next? I’m looking to develop my skills and knowledge in the area so I don’t have an interest in any particular fields.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/161368/2451

Comment: I think it very much depends on what type of problems one is dealing with. A lot of physics is about solving differential equations (ordinary and aprtial), but there are subjects that require different methods, such as Monte-Carlo or molecular dynamics.